# I need to add a CSS class just after scrolling of particular DIV

Tags: magento2, jquery

I need to add a CSS class when I scroll to a particular CLASS or DIV.

Comment: you should post this to stack overflow. nothing related to magento in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code :

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.bolck-section').offset().top + $('.bolck-section').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
          $('.inner-wrapper').addClass('testing');
        }
        else{
            $('.inner-wrapper').removeClass('testing');   
        }
    });
});
```